# Visual Studio 2012 can't build on Windows 8 due to conflicting rc.exe with SDK 7 & VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, rc.exe

I have a Windows 8 machine running Visual Studio 2010 and 2012.  The Windows SDK 7.0A was installed (presumably during the Visual Studio 2010 install) and I've recently installed Windows SDK 8.

I need to have VS2010 Pro and VS2012 Ultimate on my machine because I'm working on team projects that tie me to both.

I can successfully build my solution in VS2010 and in VS2012 if I leave the Platform Toolset set to v100. But if I change the Platform Toolset to v110 in VS2012 I get a

**LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\rc.exe'**

As suggested in answers to similar VS2012 RC.EXE questions I have copied RC.EXE and RCDLL.DLL from the Windows SDK 8 folders to the MSVC11.0\VC\bin folders putting the 32 bit versions in the bin folder and the 64 bit in the bin\x86_amd64 and bin\amd64 folders.  None of these folders is on the PATH.

I can cut and paste the error message rc.exe reference and run it from a command line so I know that it's there and it runs.  It's Version 6.2.9200.16384.

Comment: Welcome to Windows programming :)

Comment: I have a similar issue with VS 2013 Express and SDK 8.1 on Windows 7. When I run rc.exe from the command line, it seems to run perfectly but not when I run it through the IDE.

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue? Try running VS as admin, or check the permissions of rc.exe

Comment: @wiz3kid, running VS as admin didn't help. In my case, it doesn't print the full path to rc.exe. It just says `error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'`. But `$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)` is completely correct.

Comment: Is this an express edition? Have you tried running 32-bit VS?

Comment: @wiz3kid yes. I also have VS2010 Express which runs perfectly. I recently installed VS2013 Express and having the exact same problem as OP with VS2013 Express.

Comment: Try saving your PATH variable, and then clearing it and setting it to just the path to rc.exe in quotes.